# Router and Modem "argument"

Tags: router, speed, modem

I have a Cisco EA4500 wireless router and a Ubee wired modem from Time Warner.

Now I have nice speed when everything is alright, but when say a friend comes over the router connects to his phone and the Internet goes from 15 Mbps to 7 Mbps until I restart the modem and router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your friend's phone only supports older WiFi standard, thus when it connects Wireless router switches from Wifi-G to Wifi-B which is slower. I am not sure why it wouldn't switch back when your friend disconnect's though. A router restart might not be necessary, next time it happens and your friend leaves, try disconnecting from WiFi and connecting again. That should also do it, as reconnection will make your router use best supported WiFi standard.

Comment: I have tried disconnecting but it's doesn't work also I have made the router stay at one constant mode